Unity 2D following the enemy behind the player, avoiding obstacles
I'm having a problem using this script. Could you help a newbie?
I need the enemy to chase the player and avoid obstacles. Game from above
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f; 
    public float maxSpeed = 10f; 
    public float avoidanceForceMultiplier = 5f; 
    public float raySpacing = 0.5f; 
    public LayerMask obstacleLayerMask;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Transform Player;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Determine direction of movement
        Vector2 playerDirection = (Player.position - transform.position).normalized;

        // Cast rays to detect obstacles
        RaycastHit2D[] hits = new RaycastHit2D[3];
        Vector2 rayStart = transform.position * playerDirection * rb.velocity.magnitude * Time.deltaTime;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Vector2 rayDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis((i - 1) * 30f, Vector3.forward) * playerDirection;
            hits[i] = Physics2D.Raycast(rayStart, rayDirection, raySpacing, obstacleLayerMask);
            Debug.DrawRay(rayStart, rayDirection * raySpacing, Color.red);
        }

        // Calculate avoidance force
        Vector2 avoidanceForce = Vector2.zero;

        foreach (RaycastHit2D hit in hits)
        {
            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                float distanceToObstacle = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, hit.collider.transform.position);
                float distanceToRay = Vector2.Distance(rayStart, hit.point);
                avoidanceForce += Vector2.Lerp(playerDirection, hit.normal, distanceToRay / distanceToObstacle) * avoidanceForceMultiplier;
            }
        }

        // Apply avoidance force to velocity
        rb.AddForce(avoidanceForce);

        // Normalize velocity to max speed
        if (rb.velocity.magnitude > maxSpeed)
        {
            rb.velocity = rb.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
        }

        // Move towards player
        rb.velocity += playerDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}


I'm having a problem using this script. .. could you be more specific? If your question is indeed how to use this script the answer would be something along "attach it to a GameObject in your scene and adjust the values in the inspector, ensure there is an object with the tag Player in your scene and a Rigidbody attached to the same GameObject as this component" ... I suspect though that this is not your actual issue

Sorry, that's not the problem. The problem is that the enemy just starts circling around the stage and that's it, supposedly chasing the player. I still couldn’t find the error in the script, probably I’m not that experienced in this matter.

why += in rb.velocity += playerDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime; ? This should probably rather simply be rb.velocity = playerDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime; .. note though ... any previous setting of velocity and any AddForce is effectively canceled out by setting the velocity ... you shouldn't mix them

I tried removing the speed setting and putting = instead of +=. But the problem is still the same.

I noticed, that you complained about the enemy circling around the stage, that could possibly be only if you named the enemy "Player" by mistake. That means it thought it reached its destination. I can't see much logic in how you detect and avoid obstacles. What derHugo said about the velocity changes is true, you should only change it once, for example have some ifs and elses and based on some conditions set it to different values only once per Update. Also some variable names are incorrect: raySpacing is not actually spacing but ray length. The usage of Time.deltaTime is pointless in this case, you are updating velocity, not the exact position of the object.
I have made some changes and added a simple pathfinding algorythm. When making the terrain, that blocks the path, put all of the objects that are connected (there are no holes the enemy could pass through) under an empty game object (the algorythm calculates the center of mass of the objects in one group. You should create new layer for the terrain and select it in the Editor as the Obstacle Layer Mask. I've added some changeable values, like the amount of raycasts (I reccomend only using odd numbers) for some further tweaking. The movement speed of the enemy will always be the max speed.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 5f;
public float maxSpeed = 10f;
public float avoidanceForceMultiplier = 5f;
public float raySpacing = 2f;
public LayerMask obstacleLayerMask;
public float allowed_distance = 1f;
public int amount_of_raycasts = 7;

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Transform Player;
private Vector2 shortest_vector_to_target;
private Vector2 closest_point_to_target;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
}

private void Update()
{
    // Determine direction of movement
    Vector2 playerDirection = (Player.position - transform.position).normalized;

    bool ray_hit = false;

    // Cast rays to detect obstacles
    RaycastHit2D[] hits = new RaycastHit2D[amount_of_raycasts];
    Vector2 rayStart = transform.position;

    for (int i = 0; i < amount_of_raycasts; i++)
    {
        Vector2 rayDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis((i - ((amount_of_raycasts - amount_of_raycasts % 2) / 2)) * 30f, Vector3.forward) * playerDirection;
        hits[i] = Physics2D.Raycast(rayStart, rayDirection, raySpacing, obstacleLayerMask);
        Debug.DrawRay(rayStart, rayDirection.normalized * raySpacing, Color.red);
    }

    // Calculate avoidance force
    Vector2 avoidanceForce = Vector2.zero;
    float lowest_distance = 0f;

    foreach (RaycastHit2D hit in hits)
    {
        if(hit.collider != null)
        {
            closest_point_to_target = hit.collider.ClosestPoint(transform.position);
            if (!ray_hit)
            {
                lowest_distance = Vector2.Distance(closest_point_to_target, new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y));
                shortest_vector_to_target = closest_point_to_target - new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
            }
            else if(lowest_distance > Vector2.Distance(closest_point_to_target, new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y)))
            {
                lowest_distance = Vector2.Distance(closest_point_to_target, new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y));
                shortest_vector_to_target = closest_point_to_target - new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
            }
            
            Vector2 direction_to_objects = GetCenterOfParentInWorldSpace(hit.collider.gameObject.transform.parent) - new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
            Debug.DrawRay(rayStart, direction_to_objects, Color.green);
            float right_or_left = direction_to_objects.x * playerDirection.y - direction_to_objects.y * playerDirection.x;
            Debug.Log(right_or_left);
            if (right_or_left > 0)
            {
                // left
                avoidanceForce = new Vector2(-shortest_vector_to_target.y, shortest_vector_to_target.x) * avoidanceForceMultiplier;
            }
            else if (right_or_left < 0)
            {
                // right
                avoidanceForce = new Vector2(shortest_vector_to_target.y, -shortest_vector_to_target.x) * avoidanceForceMultiplier;
            }
            else avoidanceForce = new Vector2(-shortest_vector_to_target.y, shortest_vector_to_target.x) * avoidanceForceMultiplier;

            Debug.DrawRay(rayStart, shortest_vector_to_target, Color.yellow);
            avoidanceForce = avoidanceForce.normalized * maxSpeed;
            ray_hit = true;
        }
    }

    float distance_from_object = Mathf.Sqrt(shortest_vector_to_target.x * shortest_vector_to_target.x + shortest_vector_to_target.y * shortest_vector_to_target.y);

    if (ray_hit)
    {
        if (distance_from_object < allowed_distance)
        {
            rb.velocity = (avoidanceForce - shortest_vector_to_target).normalized * maxSpeed;
        }
        else if (distance_from_object > (raySpacing - raySpacing/5))
        {
            rb.velocity = (shortest_vector_to_target).normalized * maxSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = (avoidanceForce + playerDirection).normalized * maxSpeed;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        rb.velocity = (playerDirection).normalized * maxSpeed;
    }

}

Vector2 GetCenterOfParentInWorldSpace(Transform parent)
{
    if (parent.childCount == 0)
    {
        return parent.position;
    }

    Vector3 totalPosition = Vector3.zero;
    foreach (Transform child in parent)
    {
        totalPosition += parent.TransformPoint(child.localPosition);
    }

    return totalPosition / parent.childCount;
}
}

If you have some further questions about the algorythm, functionality or anything else, feel free to ask.

I tried to customize the enemy and was faced with the fact that he does not try to get around obstacles, which is very strange. But if this is not provided for in the code, then it’s understandable

It should be in the code, do you mind telling me, how you selected the layer mask?

As I understand it, it was necessary to add all the obstacles to an empty object, which should be provided with a layer/mask to bypass. Well, or I misunderstood :)

Did you create or select some kind of a layer in the upper right corner when clicking on the obstacles? And then select it in the editor as the layer mask?

I created a "Soild" layer, selected it from the enemy and assigned this layer to the empty (or not, since there are obstacles in it) object

The code works only, when the separate objects have the layer Solid, try changing the layer of each individual object.

If you have way too many objects, some changes can be made in the code, so that only the empty object can have the layer

I tried and tried to do this. The video shows the result: [link] https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aXHjgWa_o2nZM4-F52GhPPb10gBoCiyx/view?usp=drive_link

Ok, I need you to allow me acces to the video on your e-mail

[link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aXHjgWa_o2nZM4-F52GhPPb10gBoCiyx/view?usp=sharing

Ok, firstly, only the objects that are connected should be under one empty game object, for example the X you have, made from 2 separate objects. You can keep the map gameObject you have there, but create aditional empty gameObject for the connected obstacles. After that try tweaking some of the values, mainly allowed distance, that is the maximum distance, the enemy can get near the object. Try changing it to 1. Also the raySpacing determines the distance, the enemy detects the objects and tries to avoid them.

Eh, it still turns out as it was :(

if(allowed_distance >= raySpacing - raySpacing / 5)         {             Debug.Log("allowed_distance should be lowered or raySpacing should be set to a higher value");         }
set allowed_distance to 1 and set raySpacing to 2, then add this code to your Start() and then you can try changing the values. The raySpacing must be always higher than allowed_distance, I suspect that could've been the problem. This code will tell you, if the values are wrong in the editor console.

They still don't go around walls, but that could be because I set the amount_of_raycast to 0. But if it's above zero, then they don't approach the player and twitch like I don't know what

Do they twich after the previous step and after setting the amount_of_raycasts to 5?

Yes, they twitch and do not approach the player. The higher the value, the further they are from the player xd

Weird, it should work like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iNODv5KIP4WONA-IIFruXDpm97cEcwP3/view?usp=sharing

Well now I don't have access to the disk

Okay, I'll try in a couple of hours, I can't right now :(

Now this is the result. He doesn’t always go around the wall, well he doesn’t even want to approach the player, which is a shame
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12rsuouGcT9ariCRCd5bjZWJwN8UOlJ-7/view?usp=sharing

I see what the problems are, compared to my testing, your objects are vay smaller. That means that Allowed_distance set to 1 is too much in your code, if you have squares as enemies, you can use        allowed_distance = gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width;         raySpacing = 2 * allowed_distance;
in the Start() function, this should take care of these two values, when dealing with squares and you won't even have to edit them for different enemy sizes.

The second problem is that the enemy doesn't see the ground in your script, you could for example add a rectangle on the ground, put it in the same group as the other obstacles, that are touching the ground and remove its image component, so there isn't just some gray line on the ground. If the enemy still tries to go through the ground, add more invisible obstacles in the ground and link it to the objects. You don't have to do any of this when the obstacles don't touch the ground.

Also the way, you know, you don't need to add more objects in the ground is when the green ray ends in the ground. You can do that easily by putting one invisible obstacle very deep under the ground.

So I did as was said, added a wall component where the ground is, but again something wrong happens.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GnpqEcdPtyCdxsye27NrOe5JZHCiG4dz/view?usp=sharing

I see, that there are problems with this algorythm and trying to balance it through adding obstacles and other thing is inefficent. I am going to remake it.
